# Помогите послать непростой fetch запрос)

Tags: javascript, fetch

Хочу получить список новостей по API
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доку смотрю тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cognitive-services/bing-news-search/concepts/search-for-news
но, не могу понять как fetchom послать такой запрос.
Пробовал так, но не работает, подсвечивает как неверный синтаксис.

```
  methods: {
    getApiNewsData() {
        fetch('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news?category=sports&mkt=en-us', {
          Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 123456789ABCDE
          User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 822)
          X-Search-ClientIP: 999.999.999.999
          X-Search-Location: lat:47.60357;long:-122.3295;re:100
          X-MSEdge-ClientID: <blobFromPriorResponseGoesHere>
          Host: api.cognitive.microsoft.com
        }).then(response => {
          return response.json()
        }).then(result => {
          console.log(result);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        })
    },
```

Comment: При чём тут fetch, вы просто некорректно записали js-объект. Почитайте в любом учебнике, как записывать объекты правильно https://learn.javascript.ru/object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проблема с параметрами запроса, вот пример оформления

```js
    async function getNews(){
        let r =  await fetch('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/news?category=sports&mkt=en-us', {
              'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '123456789ABCDE',
              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0;Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 822)',
              'X-Search-ClientIP': '999.999.999.999',
              'X-Search-Location': 'lat:47.60357;long:-122.3295;re:100',
              'X-MSEdge-ClientID': '<blobFromPriorResponseGoesHere>',
              'Host': 'api.cognitive.microsoft.com'
            })
            let news = await r.json();
            console.log(news)
    }
getNews()
```

Но по итогу возвращает error401, так что вам надо проверить ключи подписки

Comment: Большое спасибо, Александр)